# Button resizable jquery magic margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created a button using the `<button></button>` tags. I applied `.resizable()` jQuery and it looks fine. But when I inspect element the button, it occupies the whole div with its margin-right though the margin-right is set to 0px. I've looked in the css and overrode some parts to fix it but I didn't succeed. What's causing it?

It is very similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/nagwW/13/ 
If you inspect element the button, it occupies the whole row but how could I just limit the width with respect to its real width?

Comment: are you talking about the div.ui-draggable? in IE and in firefox i don't see any weird behavior.

Comment: Yes. Inside the ui-draggable, the ui-widget is also having a long margin.

Comment: I tried it in firefox, the div of ui-draggable spans throughout the workspace. How could I limit it to the width of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI resizable function then you have to place the button element inside the element being resized, because jQuery UI's default functionality adds a div with class name "ui-resizable-handle". The clickable resize handle that you see.

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <button>Resizable</button>
</div>
```

See this JS Fiddle that I changed from jQuery UI:
http://jsfiddle.net/truthreveller/mX7Ej/3/

Comment: Thank you for that! I do have an additional question, on my code, the text inside the button is editable, I also have the `<a href="#" class="delete" style="z-index:999"></a>` beside the `<button>`. When I'm erasing the the content of the button, as I erase the last letter of the word, the button also disappears/deleted.